# Find count of rows of previous executed query in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Like in MySQL, using

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS from tablename limit 10
```

And then using

```sql
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as rows
```

to know the row count of the last executed query.

Is there any similar function/way in Snowflake from which I can find the count of rows of the previously executed query?

**Note:-** `FOUND_ROWS()` returns total count (ignoring limit clause). So I am looking for a solution which ignores the limit clause and returns the total count in snowflake

**Note**:- I don't want to use `count(*)`

**Update**

Adding brute force solution using `count(*)` from my side

```
$sql = select * from tablename limit 10;
```

using regex/any other approach I removed the limit part

So my query becomes

```
$sql_count = select * from tablename
```

Finally, execute the below query in snowflake and thus get my desire result

```
$res = select count(*) from ($sql_count)
```

**Note:-** I know this is not the standard way and also don't want this approach but for time being I using this in my project

Comment: Tried that...but not working from the snowflake UI side...I think this only supports SnowSQL i.e cli side

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of last_query_id() and a query on [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html) function.

Something like

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS from tablename limit 10;
select ROWS_PRODUCED
from table(information_schema.query_history())
where QUERY_ID=(last_query_id());
```

Comment: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS won't work in snowflake, and also your 2nd query returns the row count of the last executed query. Like if I had used limit 10 in the query, it will only return 10 as output...Not the total count without limit 10

Comment: My bad, I assumed that SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  was a valid column name, instead it is a future deprecated function see:
[link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html).
In any case, what you are trying to do relies on the fact that some RDBMS systems to a FTS even to a simple query with a LIMIT and that is not the case anymore, so this approach won't work.
Using count(*) is a valid option because SnowFlake will probably rely on table metadata and not actually read the whole table.